# Ubuntu 22-4.3 Boot Issue

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

I'm not technical but have been using the above for some time now without any issues.  However I just tried to start my desktop and got a message at boot up stage talking about "Unexpected Inconsistency Run fsck manually".
Can someone give me some guidance please so that I don't do more damage?
Cheers
Joe